# Await Tasks in Test Setup Code in xUnit.net?

Tags: c#, async-await, xunit.net

The exact situation is I'm doing E2E tests with Protractor.NET (.NET port of AngularJS's Protractor E2E framework) and I would like to make some web requests (and the API -- `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` -- has all Async/`Task` methods) to Arrange my test before I Act/Assert, only I need to do this same Arrange-ing for several tests.

I'm using xUnit.net as my test runner they use an interface (`IUseFixture<T>`) for per-fixture setup code.  It would be nice if there was a `IAsyncUseFixture<T>` that had a `Task SetFixtureAsync(T t);` or something.  I don't think such a thing exists.  Additionally I don't think constructors can use `await` either, and constructors are the only other way to execute the same block of code per-test in xUnit.net.

What are my options?  `.Result`?  Isn't that bad practice (deadlock)?

Comment: `.Result` can create a deadlock if it runs on a thread with a special synchronization context, like UI threads. In other contexts - such as console application - it would run without a problem. Do you know the context of a xUnit test?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have no idea.

Comment: You can use a synchronous api via `WebClient`

Answer (score 171, accepted):

xUnit has an `IAsyncLifetime` interface for async setup/teardown. The methods you need to implement are `Task InitializeAsync()` and `Task DisposeAsync()`.

`InitializeAsync` is called immediately after the class has been created, before it is used.

`DisposeAsync` is called just before `IDisposable.Dispose` if the class also implements `IDisposable`.

e.g.

```
public class MyTestFixture : IAsyncLifetime
{
    private string someState;

    public async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => someState = "Hello");
    }

    public Task DisposeAsync()
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void TestFoo()
    {
        Assert.Equal("Hello", someState);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use AsyncLazy

http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/08/asynchronous-lazy-initialization.html

In my case I want to run some integration tests against a self hosted web api.

```
public class BaseTest() 
{
    private const string baseUrl = "http://mywebsite.web:9999";

    private static readonly AsyncLazy<HttpSelfHostServer> server = new AsyncLazy<HttpSelfHostServer>(async () =>
    {
        try
        {
            Log.Information("Starting web server");

            var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(baseUrl);

            new Startup()
                .Using(config)
                .Add.AttributeRoutes()
                .Add.DefaultRoutes()
                .Remove.XmlFormatter()
                .Serilog()
                .Autofac()
                .EnsureInitialized();

            var server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config);
            await server.OpenAsync();

            Log.Information("Web server started: {0}", baseUrl);

            return server;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Error(e, "Unable to start web server");
            throw;
        }
    });

    public BaseTest() 
    {
        server.Start()
    }
}
```