# How to test async void DelegateCommand method containing await with xUnit?

Tags: c#, async-await, xunit, delegatecommand

It is my first time when I write unit tests for async method. I am using **xUnit**. I searched **SO** with no promissing results. Best I found, but didnt work for me, is to implement `IAsyncLifetime` from [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25519155/await-tasks-in-test-setup-code-in-xunit-net) example. I will be thankful for any hints how to trouble shoot this problem.

Currently what I have. In tested VM I have a command:

`public ICommand TestResultsCommand { get; private set; }`

And the command is initialized in the VM constructor as below:

`TestResultsCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnTestResultExecuteAsync);`

Command calls method:

```
private async void OnTestResultExecuteAsync(object obj)
        {
            TokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            CancellationToken = TokenSource.Token;

            await TestHistoricalResultsAsync();
        }
```

**TestHistoricalResultsAsync** method's signature is as below:

`private async Task TestHistoricalResultsAsync()`

Now lets go to the unit test project. Currently in test class I have a method:

```
[Fact]//testing async void
        public void OnTestResultExecuteAsync_ShouldCreateCancellationTokenSource_True()
        {
            CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = tokenSource.Token;
            _viewModel.TestResultsCommand.Execute(null);
            Assert.Equal(cancellationToken.CanBeCanceled, _viewModel.CancellationToken.CanBeCanceled);
            Assert.Equal(cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested, _viewModel.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested);
        }
```

And the test drops me an exception:

> Message: System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to
>   an instance of an object.

The stack trace for the exception is:
[image]

Thank you in advance for your time and suggestions.

Comment: `async void` should only be used for event handlers. Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Comment: Also the code should be refactored to be more SOLID so that you can properly test and maintain the code. Without a better view of the class under test, there is not much more that can be suggested as it appears you are trying to test a private member.

Comment: @Nkosi but `async void` should not be also used for `DelegateCommand`?

Comment: @Nkosi allright, in my test method I just executed command async `await Task.Run(() => _viewModel.TestResultsCommand.Execute(null));` and it worked. Solution based on this: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/97504/testing-async-commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the [problems of `async void` methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) is that they're difficult to test. For your problem, most developers do one of these:

1. Define and use an `IAsyncCommand` interface.
2. Make their logic `async Task` and public.
3. Use a framework that supports async commands, e.g., MvvmCross.

See my [MSDN magazine article on the subject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn630647.aspx) for details.

Here's an example with the second approach:

```
TestResultsCommand = new DelegateCommand(async () => await OnTestResultExecuteAsync());

public async Task OnTestResultExecuteAsync()
{
  TokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
  CancellationToken = TokenSource.Token;

  await TestHistoricalResultsAsync();
}

[Fact]
public async Task OnTestResultExecuteAsync_ShouldCreateCancellationTokenSource_True()
{
  CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
  CancellationToken cancellationToken = tokenSource.Token;
  await _viewModel.OnTestResultExecuteAsync();
  Assert.Equal(cancellationToken.CanBeCanceled, _viewModel.CancellationToken.CanBeCanceled);
  Assert.Equal(cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested, _viewModel.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested);
}
```

If you don't want to expose `async Task` methods just for the sake of unit testing, then you can use an `IAsyncCommand` of some kind; either your own (as detailed in my article) or one from a library (e.g., MvvmCross). Here's an example using the MvvmCross types:

```
public IMvxAsyncCommand TestResultsCommand { get; private set; }

TestResultsCommand = new MvxAsyncCommand(OnTestResultExecuteAsync);

private async Task OnTestResultExecuteAsync() // back to private
{
  TokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
  CancellationToken = TokenSource.Token;

  await TestHistoricalResultsAsync();
}

[Fact]
public async Task OnTestResultExecuteAsync_ShouldCreateCancellationTokenSource_True()
{
  CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
  CancellationToken cancellationToken = tokenSource.Token;
  await _viewModel.TestResultsCommand.ExecuteAsync();
  Assert.Equal(cancellationToken.CanBeCanceled, _viewModel.CancellationToken.CanBeCanceled);
  Assert.Equal(cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested, _viewModel.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested);
}
```

If you prefer the `IMvxAsyncCommand` approach but don't want the MvvmCross dependency, it's not hard to [define your own `IAsyncCommand` and `AsyncCommand` types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn630647.aspx).

Comment: Ok, thank you for the feedback. It gives me the big picture. I will have to modify my `DelegateCommand` to use `TestResultsCommand = new DelegateCommand(async () => await OnTestResultExecuteAsync());`. I was trying this before, but `DelegateCommand` didnt want to accept parameter, so I stayed with void. Ill change this. Thank you!

Comment: Hi again, I tested your approach, including creating of `AsyncCommand`, but in test method instead of `await _viewModel.OnTestResultExecuteAsync();` I had to use `await Task.Run(() => _viewModel.TestResultsCommand.Execute(null));`, otherwise seems to be that `TestHistoricalResultsAsync` is not ran async and still drops same exception.

Comment: The `await Task.Run` can't possibly fix that. Sounds like you have a race condition, and the `Task.Run` is making it (barely) take long enough. A better solution is to fix the race condition.

Comment: Honestly, `await Task.Run` fixed this. `TestHistoricalResultsAsync` returns only `Task`, and with `await Task.Run` it is executed async, no exception is thrown. You can find source code here: https://github.com/przemyslawbak/Horse_Picker/blob/b628978d74356d5af99106a55f7e23b88a6a8640/Horse_Picker.Tests/ViewModels/MainViewModelTests.cs#L118 And I am not sure what you mean by **fix the race condition**?