# Is there a way to run a setup method asynchronously before every test in an xunit test class?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, xunit

I have a set of tests with some setup required before each test.  The setup requires me to run it async and I don't particularly want to put async code running in a constructor, which is recommended by [xunit](https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context)

```cs
public class Tests
{
    private async Task SetupForEachTestAsync()
    {
        // await setup
    }

    public Tests()
    {
        SetupForEachTestAsync.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        // My test
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test2()
    {
        // My test
    }
}
```

Any recommendations on how I can improve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Await Tasks in Test Setup Code in xUnit.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25519155/await-tasks-in-test-setup-code-in-xunit-net)

Comment: Maybe this can help you [Async Unit Tests](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-unit-tests-part-1-wrong-way.html)

Comment: @devNull that sets up the class fixture (shared instance across all tests in class).  I'm looking for something that will setup before each test is run.

Comment: @chris31389 have a look [here](https://mderriey.com/2017/09/04/async-lifetime-with-xunit/) as well. Depending on where you implement the interface, it will execute per test, class, or fixture. If you implement the interface directly on your test class, it should execute the method per test

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Implement xUnit's `IAsyncLifetime` interface. It defines `InitializeAsync` and `DisposeAsync` which will be called immediately after construction and immediately before disposal, respectively.